# 'Alert whomever may read' - should it be 'whoever'?

Tags: grammaticality

I read this morning :

> ... words which leap from the second verse and alert whomever may read the epistle ... to the fact that ...

I am not clear with what exactly is going on with 'alert whomever may read'. Is 'whomever' the grammatical object of 'alert' or is it the grammatical subject of 'may read' ? Or is it both ?

So should it be 'whoever' ?

Comment: @Kris You have noted incorrectly. The relevant verb is not _alert_, but _may read_, since that is the verb with which _who(m)ever_ has a direct relation. _Who(m)ever_ is not the object of _alert_, but it is the subject of _may read_.

Answer (score 2):

It should be '**whoever**' since the pronoun must agree with the verb in the dependent clause to which the pronoun belongs (*whoever may read*):

https://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/whoever.asp

Comment: Yes, but the noun phrase "who(m)ever may read the epistle" is object of "alert", which would favour accusative "whomever".

Comment: @BillJ No it doesn't. This is because the object of "alert" is not just the one following word, but the entire clause "whoever may read the epistle titled 'Hebrews'".  Making that clause the object of a verb in a surrounding clause does *not* entail changing "whoever" into "whomever".

Comment: @RosieF Let me put it another way: there is a clash between the function of the whole NP and that of the relativised element - respectively object of "alert" and subject (note that "who(m)ever may read the epistle" is not a clause but an NP in a fused relative construction). OK now?

Comment: And pronouns which function as head of direct object are normally accusative case, i.e. "whomever". Which explains why this answer is not accurate.

Answer (score 1):

> ... *words which leap from the second verse and alert who(m)ever may read*
>   *the epistle ... to the fact that* ...

Both sound a little weird, because the construction imposes competing but unsatisfiable requirements: "who(m)ever" must be nominative because it's the subject of "may read", but it must be accusative because it's the head of the NP "who(m)ever may read the epistle" and it can't be both, so you have a quandary.

There's no way to get out of the quandary: you have to infringe one condition or the other. English is not well designed in this respect!

Comment: @NigelJ "Whoever" is preferable in contemporary language, though many would regard it as less than fully acceptable in formal style. I would be loathe to criticise "whomever" in ancient or religious texts such as your example.

Comment: Why must _who(m)ever_ be accusative to be the head of a NP? In particular when that NP (can you even call it a NP?) is a clause in which _who(m)ever_ is the subject? Just because the clause as a whole is the object of a verb, its subject doesn’t have to be in the objective case. I can’t see any real quandary here.

Comment: "... you have to infringe one condition or the other." -- there's only one, and nothing has been infringed upon. See my comment at OP.

Comment: @Kris Nonsense. You are clearly clueless about the grammar here.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Does it make sense to say that the clause as a whole is the object? A clause is not/does not mean the same thing as its subject

Comment: @sumelic It's not a clause, but a noun phrase in a 'fused' relative construction. The pronoun  is head of that NP, which serves as object of "alert", and hence would normally be accusative "whomever".  Compare "... alert him", (not "alert he").  The pronoun is also the subject in the relative clause where one would expect nominative "whoever". That is the 'clash' here. I'm surprised it's caused so much debate.